# select top value from python lists

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have the data in the following format:

```
[[(0, 0.83094628739162768), (1, 0.084504341129265095), (2, 0.08454937147910728)]
[(0, 0.89691374553960401), (1, 0.050770065151842916), (2, 0.052316189308553113)]
[(0, 0.86427304752389367), (1, 0.068236225898229905), (2, 0.067490726577876414)]
[(0, 0.06737356458000561), (1, 0.86516097670024872), (2, 0.067465458719745686)]]
```

The first values (e.g., 0, 1, 2) are group names; the second values (e.g., 0.865160) are scores. I would like to find out the group name with the highest  score in each list. So the final result should be:

```
0
0
0
1
```

Comment: Presumably each of these lists are inside a larger list?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can solve this problem in one line!

```
results = [max(collection, key=lambda x: x[1])[0] for collection in data]
```

We use a list comprehension to process each collection in the data, and then find the tuple which has the maximum second element. Then we take the first element of that tuple to get the group number.

The key here is the `key` parameter to max, you can pass an arbitrary function which will be applied to the elements of your sequence, and the result will be used as the values to compare.

Comment: Thanks very much for the solution!

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `max` function to find the highest scoring index in each list for example:

```
>>> sublist = [(0, 0.83094628739162768), (1, 0.084504341129265095), (2, 0.08454937147910728)]
>>> index = max(sublist, key=lambda tup: tup[1])[0]
```

Then you can use map to apply this to all the sublists in your main list:

```
>>> fn = lambda l : max(l, key=lambda tup: tup[1])[0]
>>> indices = map(fn, main_list)
```